# Containing image in a rounded overflow div

Tags: css

Chrome is working fine in containing an image with an overflow:hidden rounded div, however safari does not do a good job at this, the overflow: hidden doesn't seem to work here.

here's an example

[image: chrome]

[image: safari]

here is my sass code:

```
.profile-image-container
  position: relative
  top: 3px
  display: inline-block
  cursor: pointer

  .profile-image 
    width: 33px
    height: 33px
    display: block
    position: relative
    border: 2px solid $default-border-color
    position: relative
    top: -5px
    border-radius: 50%
    -moz-border-radius: 50%
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%
    overflow: hidden
```

haml:

```
.profile-image-container
    .profile-image
      =image_tag "avatar.jpg"
    %span.status.online
      %i.icon.icon-check-small
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LB2EQ/

Comment: Post, html & css and a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Share your HTML and CSS code in a JS Bin or JS Fiddle so that we can take a look at it.

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LB2EQ/

Comment: Looks fine to me in Chrome.

Comment: @j08691 Problem was in Safari ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1.** In Safari images don't inherit `border-radius`, so you'll have to add it.

**Problem 2.** Your image has a different width & height than the profile pic container which is why you'll see a very strange border-radius (only upper left) if you don't resize it.

```
.profile-image img{
    width:33px;
    height:33px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

See working solution on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LB2EQ/1/

Comment: yes, this was initially my solution before, to directly apply the border-radius to the image. but i wondered if there would be a solution to my markup above.